# Oracle APEX : press edit button then go to specify page no by checking value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Please help !!!!

I am creating a system using APEX.

I want that:

The system redirects to page no. 6 when press EDIT icon of row with the value of "payment" field in that row  is "C".

The System Redirects to page no. 7 when press EDIT icon of row with the value of "payment" field  in that row is "F".

Is possible to do that by APEX ?

I am grateful if anyone can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to rows in a classic or interactive report. You want the link column to direct the user to either page 6 or 7 of your application, depending on the value of the PAYMENT column. The value of the PAYMENT column is currently retrieved from the database in your report query, along with whatever other columns your report displays. Your question is about how to implement the logic which says:

```
if payment = 'C' then page number = 6
else if payment = 'F' then page number = 7
```

There are various places you could put that logic, but the simplest way is to include it in your report query. That way each row of the report will contain the appropriate page number for the link to redirect to.

1) Add a column to the SELECT clause of the SQL query of report:

```
decode(PAYMENT, 'C', 6, 'F', 7) "gotopage",
```

The Oracle decode function will evaluate PAYMENT for each row and return the correct page number into a report column called "gotopage".

2) Hide "gotopage" from the report.

3) Your link column should target "Page in this application", and the page to target should be: #gotopage#

Comment: Where should i put decode(payment, 'C', 6, 'F', 7) "gotopage" in new column ?

Comment: @PatrickLee I've expanded my answer a little. I made some assumptions about what you've done so far - can I suggest you provide more detail in your future questions, as you're more likely to get more answers, and the question will be easier for people to find in future if they have a similar problem.